# Roulette pattern

Tags: number-sequence

Mary was playing bingo when she noticed a logical sequence in the numbers of the balls as they came out. The numbers of the balls, in the order they came out, are shown below.

55, 52, 51, 48, 47

If the ball numbers were actually following a pattern, what would the next ball number be?

A) 46
B) 44
C) 39
D) 43

My problem is that I have no context for this puzzle. So I believe that the context is relevant to determine what the next ball number will be. Considering that they are taken cyclically, the next number would be... 44?

Comment: rot13(V oryvrir lbh zrna 44. Naq lrf gung frrz gb or gur nafjre.)

Comment: Is this a puzzle you created yourself or did you find it somewhere else? You should provide attribution on puzzles you haven't created.

Comment: The question is of a test I did. I'm afraid I don't have a detailed source. :(

Comment: @gmn_1450 Okay, one other thing I wondered, is there any reason you gave the title "Roulette Pattern" given that it is about bingo?

Comment: @Prim3numbah An urrainn dhut feuchainn ri eadar-theangachadh gu Beurla?

Comment: Please don't use MathJax to make lists, even of numbers - it's completely unnecessary and makes it harder for screen readers to parse your post. Just use commas as separators, or put two spaces after a line to make a newline.

Comment: @Prim3numbah [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) is a common way to post a comment that may contain spoilers. You can encrypt/decrypt rot13 [here](https://rot13.com/).

Comment: Bubbler, I think you meant @gmn_1450. Prim3numbah already used rot13.

Comment: Oops, sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Could you explain why?

Comment: @gmn_1450 It's cyclic like you say and the difference between to adjacent numbers alternates between -3 and -1. So last should be 47 - 3 which is option B 44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the most likely answer to this question is

> B) 44

Because

> This is a list of numbers $n$, in decreasing order, such that either $n$ or $n+1$ is divisible by $4$.

With a recursive relationship, you may be able to convince yourself that the answer is

> A) 46

Reasoning

> If $a_n$ represent the elements of the sequence then $$a_{n+1} = \begin{cases} a_n - 3, & \text{if the product of the digits of}\ a_n \text{ is odd} \\ a_n - 1, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Or perhaps with a little more maths (and the help of the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A137291)) you may convince yourself that the answer is

> D) 43

Because

> If $p_k$ represents the $k$th prime number, then these are the numbers $n$ such that $p_n^2 - 2$ is a prime, in decreasing order.